# Number of local minima of the product of a decreasing function and a linear function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f(x)=ax+b$ where $a,b>0$. Suppose that $g(x)>0, \forall x>1$ is a strictly decreasing function with $g''(x)>0$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}g(x)=C>0$ where $C$ is a constant number. Is that possible to prove that $r(x)=f(x)g(x)$ has at most one local minimum on $x\in(1,+\infty)$? If not, may I have a counterexample $f(x)$, $g(x)$?

Comment: The limit of *what* is $C$?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Sorry for the typo. The limit of $g(x)$ is $C$.

Answer (score 0):

The differential equation
$$ y'=-\frac{ay}{ax+b},\qquad y(1)=2C$$
has a solution with $y>C$ in some interval $[1,u]$.
Note that 
$$ y''=-\frac{a(ax+b)y'-a^2y}{(ax+b)^2}=\frac{2ay^2}{(ax+b)^2}>\underbrace{\frac{2aC^2}{(au+b)^2}}_{=:D}>0$$
and
$$ y'<-\frac{aC}{au+b}$$
for all $x\in[a,u]$.

If we picked $g(x)=y(x)$ (with a suitable extension beyond $u$), we'd have
$$ r'(x)=f'(x)g(x)+f(x)g'(x)=ay+(ax+b)y'=0$$
for all $x\in(1,u)$. 
But we want *strict* local minima, don't we? To this, some tiny perturbation helps:

For arbitrary natural $n$ and for some yet to be specified constants $s>0$,   let
 $$g(x)=\begin{cases}y(x)+s\sin \frac{n\pi x}{u}&\text{if }1\le x\le u\\\text{left as exercise}&\text{if }x>u\end{cases}$$
It is straightforward that the lower branch can be picked suitably to guarantee $g\in C^2[1,\infty)$, $g''(x)>0$ for all $x\in [1,\infty)$, and $\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)=C$,
provided the upper branch gives us $g(u)>C$, $g'(u)<0$, and $g''(x)>0$ for all $x\in [1,u]$.
And indeed, we have
$$ g'(x)=y'(x)+\frac{sn\pi}{u}\cos\frac{n\pi x}{u}<0$$
for all $x\in[1,u]$, provided we pick $s<\frac{aCu}{(au+b)n\pi}$.
Also,
$$ g''(x)=y''(x)-\frac{sn^2\pi^2}{u^2}\sin\frac{n\pi x}{u}>0$$
for all $x\in[1,u]$, provided we pick $s<\frac{2aC^2u^2}{(au+b)^2n^2\pi^2}$.

Now what about the extrema of $r$?
For $1<x<u$, we have
$$\begin{align}r'(x)&=f'(x)g(x)+f(x)g'(x)\\&=f'(x)(g(x)-y(x))+f(x)(g'(x)-y'(x))\\
&=s\cdot\left(a\sin\frac{n\pi x}{u}+(ax+b)\frac{n\pi }{u}\cos\frac{n\pi x}{u}\right)\end{align}$$
which has several isolated simple zeroes, about half of which lead to strict local minima of $r(x)$.