# Direction changes in product of functions

Tags: calculus, derivatives, monotone-functions

Suppose $f(x) = g(x) h(x)$ and the number of direction changes in both $g$ and $h$ are known. Is there a simple way to prove that the number of direction changes in $f$ is bounded by the number of direction changes of $g$ and $h$?

As a simple case, consider $h$ as monotonic - it seems intuitive that $f$ cannot have more direction changes than does $g$.

Comment: What do you mean by direction changes? Do you mean the number of points which are a local minimum or local maximum? If this is what you mean, try using the derivative test to obtain an upper bound.

Comment: Yep! Anyhow, after some searching: a suitable counterexample is found at this post:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2718439/number-of-local-minima-of-the-product-of-a-decreasing-function-and-a-linear-func